# Save and extract fingerprint to database

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I am using digital persona U.are.U 5100 fingerprint reader. The problem I'm facing is, that the enrollment will only be saved temporarily. How can I save it to the database?

```
/// <summary>
/// Handler for when a fingerprint is captured.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="captureResult">contains info and data on the fingerprint capture</param>
private void OnCaptured(CaptureResult captureResult)
{
    try
    {
        // Check capture quality and throw an error if bad.
        if (!_sender.CheckCaptureResult(captureResult)) return;

        count++;

        DataResult<Fmd> resultConversion =  
        FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromFid(captureResult.Data, 
                                           Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);

        SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "A finger was captured.   
                    \r\nCount:  " + (count));

        if (resultConversion.ResultCode !=  
            Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
        {
            _sender.Reset = true;
            throw new Exception(resultConversion.ResultCode.ToString());
        }

        preenrollmentFmds.Add(resultConversion.Data);

        if (count >= 4)
        {
            DataResult<Fmd> resultEnrollment =  
            DPUruNet.Enrollment.CreateEnrollmentFmd(Constants.Formats.
                                                    Fmd.ANSI,  
                                                    preenrollmentFmds);

            if (resultEnrollment.ResultCode == 
                Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
            {
                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "An enrollment FMD was 
                            successfully created.");
                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Place a finger on the 
                            reader.");
                preenrollmentFmds.Clear();
                count = 0;
                return;
            }
            else if (resultEnrollment.ResultCode == 
                     Constants.ResultCode.DP_ENROLLMENT_INVALID_SET)
            {
                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Enrollment was 
                unsuccessful.  Please try again.");
                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Place a finger on the  
                reader.");
                preenrollmentFmds.Clear();
                count = 0;
                return;
            }
        }

        SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Now place the same finger on the            
        reader.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
           // Send error message, then close form
            SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Error:  " + ex.Message);                
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread. But I just recently figured out how to do it using digital persona.

try using

```
Fmd.SerializeXml(fmd);
```

it returns string so you can save it directly as string in your database and retrieve as is.

then when decoding try using

```
Fmd.DeserializeXml(*retrieved string from database*);
```

It returns fmd, so you can now compare it to your current input.

Comment: Hi, if I have about hundred fmds stored as hundred strings in my DB, in order to compare them (for authorizing a user), should I bring all of the fmds from DB? what is the best practice?

Comment: @Lichte Hi, could you resolve it ? Any Luck ? I'm looking for the same ...

Comment: After a while I decided to store the fingerprints as files  on the device where the fingerprint is connected. I think it is safer, as part of the encryption key is the mac of the device itself. so even if the encrypted files  will be compromised, they could not be decrypted without the device. @DavidNoreña